# self invoking function with setTimeout closure, variable access

Tags: javascript

How would I get access to the  `a_var` that is in `setTimeout`, from the outter `someFunction`?

Thanks.

```
function someFunction(){
             (function why(){
                       setTimeout(function(){

                          var a_var='help I wanna get out!';
                         return a_var;//<-useless?

                      }, 25);
                   })();
        };
```

Comment: the return is indeed useless in the timeout callback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a_var in a higher scope, like so:

```
var a_var = 'I can help from here';
function someFunction(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    a_var = "help I wanna get out!";
  }, 25);
}
someFunction();
console.log(a_var); // logs 'I can help from here'
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(a_var);
}, 30); // logs 'help I wanna get out!';
```

Comment: The declaration of `a_var` has to be even higher than this!?....`function someFunction(){var a_var; (function why(){ a_var='help I wanna get out!';return a_var;//<-useless? })();};`

Comment: It looks like you've got some unnecessary parts in there, it might be helpful to read more about javascript closures: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg36/